# Vertex Points in Locally Finite Alexandroff Spaces

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to prove the second implication of the following theorem from https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/eckhardt/P124_941.pdf.

A topological space $X$ is termed locally finite if each point $P$ in $X$ has a finite neighborhood and a finite closed set containing $P$.

A point $P$ with $CP = \{P\}$ is called a vertex point.

Where $CQ$ is the smallest closed set containing $Q$ and $CP$ the smallest closed set containing $P$

Theorem 8

Let $X$ be a locally finite Alexandroff space. Then

1. Each set $C P$ contains at least one vertex point.
2. If $C P \neq C Q$, then there is a vertex point in one of these sets which is not contained in the other set.

---

Proof of 1:

If $CP \neq \{P\}$, then there exists $Q \in CP$ such that $Q \neq P$.
from previous theorems we get that $P \notin CQ$.
As $Q \in CP$, then every closed set containing $P$ contains also $Q$.
Note that $CP$ is a closed set that contains $Q$ .
As $CQ$ is the intersection of all the closed sets that contain $Q$ then $CQ \subset CP$.
Therefore, as $CQ \subset CP$ and $P \in CP$ but $P \notin CQ$, we get that $\arrowvert CQ \arrowvert < \arrowvert CP \arrowvert$, that is $CQ$ has fewer points than $CP$.

Note that doing the same process iteratively with $CQ$, we obtain a vertex point. As a matter of fact, as $X$ is locaaly finite, then $CP$ is finite, which guarantees that there are finite iterations. Moreover, from previous theorems we got that $\arrowvert CS \arrowvert < \arrowvert CH \arrowvert$ everytime $S \in CH$. Therefore, we will finally obtain a closed set $CY = \{Y\}$ such that $CY \subset CP$. Hence, $CP$ has a vertex point.

---

I really don't know how to get to conclusion 2, taking into account that if I follow the same idea of the proof of 1, we can get to various vertex points, nevertheless I don't know how to guaranee that those vertex point sets are in fact different, that is, there exist a vertex point in one of the sets which is not contained in the other.

Another thing that I'm confused about is that if for example we have that $CP = \{P,Q,S\}$ and $CR = \{R,Q,S\}$, the sets are in fact distinct, nevertheless when repeat the process of 1, we get that we have the same two options to start, and therefore we will get the same vertex points.

Comment: Both parts of the theorem are false; for instance, consider the indiscrete topology on a finite set with at least 2 points.  In particular, in your argument for part 1, it is not correct to conclude that $P\not\in CQ$.

Comment: Part 1 is correct if you add the additional assumption that $X$ is $T_0$.  Part 2 is still wrong, though; the counterexample you propose in your final paragraph can indeed be realized.  Maybe there are some additional hypotheses you have left out?  Where did you find this theorem statement?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I left out the assumption that $X$ is $T_0$. For part 2, I found it in this paper https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/eckhardt/P124_941.pdf , theorem 8 in page 13 , where they have a proof for it but I couldn't understand it.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Part 2 of this theorem is just wrong; the example you propose in your final paragraph can be turned into a counterexample.  For instance, consider the space $\{P,Q,R,S\}$ with the topology generated by the sets $\{P\},\{R\},\{P,Q,R\},$ and $\{P,R,S\}$.  Then the vertex points are $Q$ and $S$ and $CP=\{P,Q,S\}$ and $CR=\{R,Q,S\}$ are different but contain the same vertex points.